# Paint a graph in Java using AWT

Tags: java, graph, awt

I'm searching a possibility to paint a graph in Java using AWT. My knowledge of Java is still basic, so this is mainly for getting used to AWT, even if it's already "old".

-Felix

Comment: Exactly, that would be what I would need. Is there any sort of open-sourced library?

Comment: Check out JFreeChart for a good open-source library. However, because it's quite high-level it won't teach you much about AWT (or Swing) unless you look through the actual source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
JFrame f = new JFrame();
JPanel p = new JPanel () {
     public void paint(Graphics g){
         Graphics2D g2d = printImg.createGraphics();
         g2d.drawString("123", 10, 10);        
     }
 }
 f.add(p);
 f.setSize(100,100);
 f.setVisible(true);
```

Small example of how to paint in Swing components, the same in AWT.
The paint method is the one where you can paint. To see what you can paint (Rectangles, circles, ...) you can look at the Java API of the "Graphics" or "Graphics2D" class.